# Progress Bar for Background Process in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, progress-bar

I have a couple of processes in my Rails application that call to an external web API - and take a long time to finish. I've considered moving them to process in the background.

I would like to be able to show the user the progress of the background process (i.e. a progress bar).

First, are there any good tutorials/learning resources on implementing a progress bar with jQuery in Rails (not related to a file upload process)? I've seen a lot of resources on displaying the graphic - but not a lot of information on how to hook the graphic updating to the actual background process.

Second, as I consider the various gems for background processing, is there one that would work better with a progress bar (i.e. Delayed Jobs, Resque, Sidekiq)?

Thank you

Comment: Look at this external post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sdruby/0OIj0XKsnrg

Comment: I say it doesn't matter what gem you use for background processing. Either way, you'll probably need to manually update some status table to keep track of the progress

Comment: It's taken me some time to come back to this - but apparently Fro__oo's suggestion uses a method (current) that was proposed in a delayed_jobs branch request, but was never merged into the main project.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a blog post about using [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) + [SidekiqStatus](https://github.com/cryo28/sidekiq_status) + [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) theme progress bar = to implement a progress bar.  I know it's been a while since this has been asked but hopefully, others will find it useful:

### [How to Implement a Progress Bar Using Sidekiq Status](https://web.archive.org/web/20170212052301/http://www.sunwooyang.com/posts/how-to-implement-a-progress-bar-using-sidekiq-status)

---

[image: progress bar sample]

Comment: Not available any more

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the process of moving my blog to digital ocean. It'll be back up soon.

Comment: The site is back up! Though now it's on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I created a gem `'sk_progress_bar'` where I implemented `"Progress Bar for Sidekiq Workers in Rails`"!

I hope it will be useful for everyone!

You can download gem here:

Rubygems.org

```
https://rubygems.org/gems/sk_progress_bar
```

Git

```
https://github.com/Kondzolko/sk_progress_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The gem [Progress Job](https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job) looks promising for providing progress updates on background jobs. At this time it looks like it works with DelayedJob.

Answer (score -1):

Use the startAjax event to trigger a function that hide/shows the progress bar.

I [just answered this question in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386487/bootstrap-progress-bar-using-get/14386958#14386958).

The url for the jqueryui progress meter docs is http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: While the requester does mention wanting to use jQuery to update a progress bar, this does not adequately answer the true question, which is how to get the progress information in the first place.